# ET Enterprise Cloud 2.0 - Query Permanent Held Status by BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, enterprise

I need help to build a query.

We have over forty BU's and we use DE's. We want to have better visibility before we send the the email as who will receive the email. We have unsubscribes by BU but HELD status is at the ENT level.

Comment: Please show us what you have for a query currently.

Comment: SELECT A.EmailAddress, S.Status
FROM [SubscriberProfile] as A
INNER JOIN _Subscribers as S
ON A.EmailAddress = S.EmailAddress
Where S.Status = 'held'

Comment: this is a query within the BU. but i end up getting everyone at the Enterprise level.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the _subscribers view is for all subscribers across the enterprise account.  There is not currently a way to restrict that view to just the BU.